# Routed event with multiple user control depth

Tags: wpf

I have a Main window that has a user control. This UC in turn has a UC, and so on. This chain from Main window to the final child UC is 4 levels deep. I want to be able to cascade an event from the last child UC up to the main window. I have accomplished simple routed events when the main window has ACCESS to the user control so that it can add an event handler as follows:

```
    MainWindow.xaml:
    // TCardViewer is a user control with a name on the form
    TCardViewer.Tap += TCardViewer_Tap;


    void TCardViewer_Tap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //handle it    
    }
```

I don't have access to the last child element, as it is a nested user control and no "instance" of it exists for my main window to bind to. How can I go about doing this? Do I need to have each level bind to it to carry the event upwards, or is there a way my main window can somehow tap into the last child's routed event without having an "instance" of it to work with. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: Used an attached property in the main window.

```
tcard:TCardViewIncidentPanel.Tap="TCardViewer_Tap"
```

In my mainwindow.xaml window property, where TCardViewer_Tap is a function inside mainwindow.xaml.